# Qt Python: QTextEdit - display input

Tags: python, qt, qtextedit

I have a QTextEdit... it works with 'clear()' when a pushbutton calls 'CleanComments' to clean the input done by the user. Here is the code:

```
def CleanComments(self):
    self.textEditInput.clear()

def showInput(self):
    print "show input: %s" % self.textEditInput.show()

def buildEditInput(self):
    self.textEditInput = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.boxForm)
    self.textEditInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 500, 100))
```

The only problem is, that when 'showInput' is called to display the content on QTextEdit using "show()", it gives "" show input: 'None' "". So, what is missing here?

All comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the contents of a `QTextEdit` as a simple string, use the `toPlainText()` method.

```
print "show input: %s" % self.textEditInput.toPlainText()
```

There is also the `toHtml()` method. For even more options, you can work directly with the `QTextDocument` from `QTextEdit.document()`.

Comment: Since `toPlainText()` returns a `QString`, you may need to convert it so Python can print the text:

`print "show input: %s" % str(self.textEditInput.toPlainText())`

Comment: Nah, PyQt implements 'magic' python methods like `__str__`, you should be fine.

Comment: That's it... worked nicely. Thanks GNUD and COONJ -- it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Your showInput method is printing the return from the show() method, which returns None. If you want to print the current text in the edit, use:

```
print "show input: %s" % self.textEditInput.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Method show from widget is used to display the widget on a screen. For example if you have main window, you call show to display it to user. If you wish to retrieve data from some edit, be it line edit or text edit, you should use text() method. Like this:

```
def showInput(self):
    print "show input: %s" % self.textEditInput.text()
```

Comment: QTextEdit doesn't provide the text() method. QLineEdit does.  But toPlainTExt() or toHtml() are your options here.