# Save the contents of a qtextedit to .txt file

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a question related to qtextedit. I have a GUI in which the Qtextedit widget gets populated once when i press a button (basically after running a process). Now i want to save the contents of the qtext edit widget to *.txt file.

I referred the docs but i did'nt get any particular method like gettext() of a qlineedit.

How to do this ? help me with this

[image]

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with? Is it that you don't know how to get the text out of the widget, or how to save that into a file?

Comment: i have problem with both i want the contents to be saved into a text file, my gui looks like the one in the picture which i attached.

Comment: Then this is probably two separate questions, both of which are trivially answered elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2063633/3001761 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5214578/3001761, for example. How the GUI looks isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Huummm ..., I document have it, isn't it ?

In `QTextEdit` have 2 method available for get text in frame;

[QString QTextEdit.toHtml (self)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#toHtml)

[QString QTextEdit.toPlainText (self)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#toPlainText)

little example;

```
.
.
.
yourQTextEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit() 
.
.
.
with open('log.txt', 'w') as yourFile:
    yourFile.write(str(yourQTextEdit.toPlainText()))
```

Comment: i don't want it in html but i have to check toPlainText, i thought it as a different method because i was searching on the lines for getText

Comment: `QString QTextEdit.toPlainText (self)` is also can used. Or use class `QtGui.QPlainTextEdit` to get pure plain text easy.

Comment: toPlainText works and sorry man.... actually i was looking for gettext that's y i could'nt find it

Comment: You should really handle files using the `with` context manager.

Comment: Thank for advice. I will improve it. @jonrsharpe

Comment: No problem - you don't need to explicitly `close` when you use `with` (that's one of the benefits) - the file is close when you leave the `with` block.